# Having trouble calling this weird method (<T>)

Tags: java, methods

Searching online, I found a method I needed that can merge arrays. It was designed to take as many parameters as necessary, and of any datatype. This is what I need it to do, but I don't know how to properly call it! Here's what the method looks like:

```
public static <T> T[] arrayMerge(T[]... arrays)
{
    blah blah blah
}
```

The only way I could think of to call it was `byte[] result = arrayMerge(a, b, c);` (where a, b, and c all refer to byte[]s), but this doesn't work. How can I call it? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think generic types can only work with classes, not primitive types. So, they would work for `Byte[]`, not `byte[]`.

Comment: Oh okay, I'll use something else then (changing to Byte[], merging them, then changing back is too clunky for me)

Comment: Well, you could modify the method you got and change the generic parameter `T` for `byte` so you can use it with `byte[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change the method to be non-generic and be specific to `byte[]` if that is what you want. For example (not sure if it is the best impl):

```
public static byte[] arrayMerge(byte[]... arrays) {
    int count = 0;
    for (byte[] array : arrays) 
        count += array.length;

    byte[] mergedArray = new byte[count];

    int start = 0;
    for (byte[] array : arrays) {
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, mergedArray, start, array.length);
        start += array.length;
    }
    return mergedArray;
}
```

Then use:

```
byte[] result = arrayMerge(new byte[0], new byte[0], new byte[0]);
```